# How to scan available WiFi access points while in master mode in Linux

Tags: linux, wifi

In Linux, when the wifi interface (`wlan0`) is in "Managed" mode, we can run the following command to scan available WiFi access points:

```
$iwlist wlan0 scan
```

But this command stops to work when the interface is in "Master" mode:

```
$iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0    No scan results
```

Is this a hard constraint of WiFi chip, or a limit in Linux software?

Is there a way to scan for available WiFi access points while the current interface itself is in "Master" mode, i.e. itself is an Access Point.

Answer (score 1):

Very good question. Results of some minor research on the matter are as follows.

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/mac80211/cfg.c#L2439

In `ieee80211_scan()` one can notice that the function tests `NL80211_FEATURE_AP_SCAN` flag in the set of features advertised by the underlying wireless device driver. That effectively means that, indeed, it's a constraint, but it's likely imposed by the specific vendor / driver / device rather than by Linux generic code.

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/C/ident/NL80211_FEATURE_AP_SCAN

One may try to search for the said feature flag among the available wireless drivers. For example, my Wi-Fi card needs `ath9k` driver, and I don't see the latter in the list of drivers that advertise the said feature. Hence, my Wi-Fi card can't scan while in AP/master mode. Indeed, when I run (as root) `iwlist dev_name scan` or `iw dev dev_name scan`, I observe very similar output (`Interface doesn't support scanning : Operation not supported` and `command failed: Operation not supported (-95)` respectively).

Comment: My Wi-Fi driver is `brcmfmac`. I cannot find it having NL80211_FEATURE_AP_SCAN feature.